# Is app_process executable directly?

Tags: operating-system, native-library

When I ran the "file" command on app_process32 and app_process64, they are listed as shared objects (so files). From my understanding, .so files are not directly executable.

However, based on what I read online (https://elinux.org/Android_Zygote_Startup and https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/902), it seems that app_process can be executed directly?

Example, I see snippets such as

```
adb shell app_process -Djava.class.path=/data/local/tmp/classes.dex /sdcard shellService.Main
```

```
app_process [java-options] cmd-dir start-class-name [options]
```

Perhaps my understanding of app_process is wrong?

Comment: Yes it is. [Why and how are some shared libraries runnable, as though they are executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223385/262728).

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif, now it makes sense to me.